# How do I delete a family member’s Apple Watch iCloud backup?

Tags: icloud, backup, apple-watch

How do I delete a family member’s Apple Watch iCloud backup? The watch is setup as a standalone phone line. I used my iPhone to setup my child’s watch.

Answer (score 1):

> The watch is setup as a standalone phone line. I used my iPhone to setup my child’s watch.

If you used [Family Setup for an Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211768) (it sounds like you did) then you just turn off iCloud Backup in the Watch.

From Apple Support: [If you used Family Setup for a family member's Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204518):

> To turn off iCloud backups for that watch, open the Settings app on the managed Apple Watch, go to **[account name] →  iCloud →  iCloud Backups**, then **turn off iCloud Backups**.

<sup>Emphasis Mine</sup>

If you didn’t set it up as a part of Family setup, then unfortunately, it is part of your iPhone backup and there isn’t a way to “detangle” them from each other.

> Your Apple Watch data is backed up to the iPhone that it's paired with. This happens automatically as long as your iPhone and Apple Watch are near each other, so you don't need to do anything to keep your watch backed up.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have set the Apple Watch with your iPhone, you can also delete the backups from your iPhone.

On your iPhone, go to **Settings > General > iPhone Storage > Watch** [the Apple Watch app]. Then, you should see the watch's backups, simply swipe right on the backup you want to delete.

Comment: This does not apply for family setup. Family setup watches get backed directly to iCloud.

Comment: @DeepSpace101 Then you can just go to Settings > [family member account name] > iCloud and turn off iCloud Backups, it should erase the data too.